# How can i access to my elements which are content projected?

Tags: angular

I have chip-list component. Inside it, I projected one input and one other component. But I want to access the input.

```html
 <app-chip-list>
     <input #input [id]="autoCompleteSearchInput" type="text" autoComplete="off"
        class='input-underline search-bar idented-text' [placeholder]="placeholder" 
     [formControl]="search" />
     
     <app-chips [chips]="chips" class="chips" (removeChip)="removeChip($event)"></app-chips>

 </app-chip-list>
```

Now in my chip list component, I need access to these projected elements.

For example to the whole `app-chips` component and to my input.

How can I access them?

Answer (score 2):

Use `@ContentChild`:

```js
@ContentChild('input') theInput: ElementRef;
@ContentChild(ChipsComponent) theChipsComponent: ChipsComponent;
```